# Get return value from given function using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the Browser render source code in HTML following format.
There is button and on that button click one java-script function is called and I want the Return value from java script  function.
**Return value from that function.**
Please refer below code for your reference,

[image]

Thanks,
Digambar K.

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing? what is the error?

Comment: Rookie I want want the value return by function.

Comment: Is this asp.net generated code and you want to return value from server side?

Comment: You are saying what you want. Show us what you tried and what error you are getting and perhaps someone can help

Comment: Its Browser render HTML code and I want the value return by the Javascript function that will be call on button click.

Comment: I am not sure the webForm_DoPortBackWithOptions returns a value. What exactly are you trying to achive?

Comment: What value will be return by WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions function on button click event and I want to catch that value in certain veriable..

Answer (score 0):

**This is way to get return value using javascript:**

```
function myFunction(value1,value2,value3)
{
}

var returnValue = myFunction("1",value2,value3);

if(returnValue.value1  && returnValue.value2)
{
//Do some stuff
}
```

**This is way to get return value using jquery:**

```
function getMachine(color, qty) {
    var retval;
    $("#getMachine li").each(function() {
        var thisArray = $(this).text().split("~");
        if(thisArray[0] == color&& qty>= parseInt(thisArray[1]) && qty<= parseInt(thisArray[2])) {
            retval = thisArray[3];
            return false;
        }
    });
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
OnClientClick="return //javascript code"
```

instead of

```
onclick
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var returnValue;

$(document).ready (function(){

      var myButton =  $("#yourbuttonsid");

      var originalEventHandler = myButton[0].onclick;

       myButton.click(function(e) {

             returnValue = originalEventHandler();

          });


});

//Here you can do anything with returnValue
```

Comment: Please refer below code onclick event.....                                                onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_e2756687_372a_49e0_b01e_e7c91e124d01$ff131$ctl00$ctl00$btnCheckOverbook", "", true, "", "", false, true))" type="button" jQuery17107423179513001774="14"